# Which came first, the definite or indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

Historically speaking, which came first? I remember reading a textbook that gave a concise historical timeline of the integral, and context to why the "antiderivative" uses the same Leibniz "summation" notation as the definite integral. Unfortunately, I can't remember for the life of me what the textbook was.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems

Comment: From Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott, Abbott says that "Historically, the concept of integration was defined as the inverse process of differentiation. In other words, the integral of a function $f$ was understood to be a function $F$ that satisfied $F'=f$ . Newton, Leibniz, Fermat, and the other founders of calculus then went on to explore the relationship between antiderivatives and the problem of computing areas."

Comment: It's not clear that your question has an answer, as it's possible that neither concept sprang into existence in an instant of time. I've been given to understand that Archimedes computed some definite integrals, but I never heard that he had any concept of antiderivative. But I don't know much.

Comment: @bof . Archimedes' integration methods were lost until the 19th century CE when a medieval manuscript was seen to be written over an incompletely-erased copy of a letter from Archimedes to  a friend, explaining them. The computations he needed were laborious, as you would expect without the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Your question is better suited to the [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). Please see if there are any duplicates there before you ask.